Send email notification based on excel due date via Power Automate
I'm trying to build a Power Automate flow which send an email reminder once the due date is today date.
In fact, I'm not able to find a way filtering the rows containing the today date. It seems the output is decimal rather than date format.
Excel table

Filter array

Error message

Filter array step config

Condition step config

The flow enter


Any help would be great...kind of stuck.
Thanks !
